# Error fetching data with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to edit some data using boostrap and ajax, however when I run the code an error occurs.

The error is on the line

`onclick="editUser('.$row->id.');"`

How do I fix this?

My JavaScript code is

```
function edit(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('edit')?>/" + id,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('[name="name"]').val(data.name);
            $('[name="id"]').val(data.id);
            $('[name="name"]').focus();
            $('#edit').modal('show'); // show bootstrap modal when complete loaded
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error ajax');
        }
    });     

}
```

My HTML code is

```
<?php
    $no = 1;
    foreach ($user as $row) {               
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->nik; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>                  
    <td align="center">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editUser('.$row->nik.');" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> &nbsp;
    </td>
<?php $no++; }?>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please provide what error you are getting.

Comment: error alert show cannot success

Comment: dump site_url('edit') and check your url rendrerd

Comment: when I change `onclick="editUser('.$row->nik.');"` with `onclick="editUser('123456');"` ajax can work

Comment: Just made it more readable and fixed the grammar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bit of php/javascript soup. Your href value needs to be enclosed in php tags. Change:

```
 onclick="editUser('.$row->nik.');"
```

to

```
 onclick="editUser('<?php echo $row->nik;?>');"
```

Comment: Thanks @hairmot, I have tried but instead form modal not appear

Comment: could you have a look in developer tools (f12) at how the anchor element is rendering in the browser?

Comment: oops just edited my answer - try again (i'd left a character in that didnt belong)

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the hairmot's answer:

You would also like to escape any characters that would interfere with the html:

```
onclick="editUser('<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row->nik) ?>');"
```